# Conversão do Resultado do hibernate para json

Tags: java

Preciso de uma ajuda com o caso de converter o resultado do SQL do hibernate em json.

cheguei até a etapa que está convertendo correto, mais o mesmo não vem com o nome definido da coluna, e eu estava precisando que viesse no json o resultado com o nome da respectiva coluna.

SQL:

```
select locationApiAcp as acp from Pro
```

Função:

```
public List<Map<String,Object>> listByNativeQuery(String query) {
    Query nativeQuery = manager.createNativeQuery(query);

    return nativeQuery.getResultList();
}
```

Chamada:

```
List<Map<String,Object>> listObj = local._runLibrary(cq);

    Gson gs = new Gson();

    String json = gs.toJson(listObj);
    System.out.println(json);
```

Resultado final não saindo com o nome da coluna:

```
["/api/"]
```

---Edit---
Uma pequena solução que achei usando uma conexão paralela a JPA. Não sei se seria o correto ou daria para fazer com a conexão da própria jpa.

Classe para conversão posterior:

```
public class JsonApi {
private String status;
private List<HashMap<String, String>> rows = new ArrayList<>();

public void _addRow(HashMap<String, String> map) {
    this.rows.add(map);
}

public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public List<HashMap<String, String>> getRows() {
    return rows;
}

public void setRows(List<HashMap<String, String>> rows) {
    this.rows = rows;
}}
```

Processamento do ResultSet:

```
this.json.setStatus("200");

while (this.rs.next()) {

    ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();

    for (int i = 1; i <= rsmd.getColumnCount(); i++) {
        String column = rsmd.getColumnLabel(i);
        map.put(column, this.rs.getString(column));
    }

    this.json._addRow(map);

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Fiz um pequeno teste com o código:

```
List<Map<String,Object>> listObj = new ArrayList<>();
Map<String,Object> map1 = new HashMap<>();
map1.put("f1", "v1");
map1.put("f2", 1L);
listObj.add(map1);
Map<String,Object> map2 = new HashMap<>();
map2.put("f1", 1.2D);
listObj.add(map2);

Gson gs = new Gson();
String json = gs.toJson(listObj);
System.out.println(json);
```

E obtive a saída:

> [{"f1":"v1","f2":1},{"f1":1.2}]

Portanto, o código de serialização corretamente.

Algo importante que deve ser entendido é que o tipo genérico da lista (neste caso: `Map<String,Object>`) é apenas uma verificação em tempo de compilação, não uma garantia em tempo de execução.

No caso, o método [`getResultList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Query.html#getResultList()) não informa o tipo genérico. Na realidade, em geral, quando não há uma entidade JPA selecionada, o Hibernate retorna um *array* contendo os valores dos campos na ordem em que foram selecionados na consulta. Como você selecionou apenas um campo, provavelmente o hibernate está apenas retornando uma lista onde cada elemento é uma string com o valor do campo.

Portanto, o que está errado no código é que ele assume que o tipo errado em cada item da lista resultante da consulta.

Se você precisar retornar os valores como um mapa, ou qualquer outra estrutura, precisa rearranjar os valores da lista de modo que seja compatível com a estrutura desejada para o JSON.

Ao fazer uma consulta como esta, inspecione via debugging quais valores o Hibernate realmente retorna e nunca assuma a tipagem sem confirmar antes, afinal consultas nativas não tem as garantias de mapeamento das entidades JPA.

Comment: Utluiz, não sei se seria o caso, mais acabei solucionando com uma conexão paralela ao que eu venho utilizando com o hibernate. Eu editei meu post com o que eu consegui.

Comment: @KelvinStangOenning A solução com JDBC parece boa. Pode postá-la como resposta à sua própria pergunta é aceitá-la como certa.

Comment: não consigo mais adicionar resposta pois aparenta o tópico estar como pendente pela administração, mais coloquei ali como editado. No caso ali após o "--Edit--" estou processando o ResultSet na mão.